# Does anyone have a config to process AWS CloudFront/S3 logs with AWStats (or similar sw)?

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awstats, amazon-cloudfront

I don't want to give an external company like s3stat access to my logs.  I know that AWS logs S3 and Cloud Front in a format readable by AWStats. Has anyone used AWSats to analyze them?

S3stat used to offer a hosted version of their software that was in beta but I believe it has been discontinued.

I am not tied to AWStats, I will consider other self hosted web log analyzing software options.

Comment: I struggled a long time until I came upon this on a forum: LogFormat="ogFormat="%date %time2 %x-edge-location %sc-bytes %c-ip %cs-method %cs(Host) %cs-uri-stem %sc-status %cs(Referer) %cs(User-Agent) %cs-uri-query %cs(Cookie) %x-edge-result-type %x-edge-request-id". Now awstats doesn't complain at all. The format given in the answer didn't work for me (dropped records or corrupted depending how I tweaked things). Use this to update awstats: perl /usr/share/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl S3/bucket/*  > awstats/input.txt && perl /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -update -config=XXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use AWStats with S3, but would suggest there are 3 problems with processing the logs:

1. You need to obtain the data - it is stored on S3

   With Cloudfront, AWS gives you the option of which bucket you wish to use - it does not have to be the source (origin) bucket. You can easily setup a specific bucket for your logs and can mount this via [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) - this should provide the simplest access to the files - retaining the timestamps, etc. that are often needed for incremental processing of logs. Alternatively, if you don't wish to mount a bucket as a local file system, you could use [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd), [aws](http://timkay.com/aws/), or one of the SDKs to download the files. (There is a python script (using boto) for this purpose - [here](http://imthi.com/blog/linux/download-process-amazon-cloudfront-logs-with-awstats.php) - although, I can't vouch for its effectiveness.)
2. You need to decompress and combine the logs

   Cloudfront logs are compressed (gzipped), and stored as multiple files - the filenames contain the date and hour (e.g. `XXXXXXXXXXXXX.YYYY-MM-DD-HH.XXXXXXXXX`), although, there can be multiple files per hour. The files can be decompressed with `gunzip` and combined with the (AWStats provided tool) `logresolvemerge.pl`.
3. You need to provide a custom log format to AWStats

   The file format is tab separated and resembles:

   ```
   date time x-edge-location sc-bytes c-ip cs-method cs(Host) cs-uri-stem sc-status cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs-uri-query
   2011-06-27  08:31:10    JFK1    587 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net   /path/to/your/file  304 http://www.mydomain.com/page/requesting/file    User-agent-string -
   ```

   You would, therefore, [setup](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#LogFormat) AWStats with:

   ```
   LogType=W
   LogSeparator="\t"
   LogFormat="%time2 %cluster %bytesd %host %method %virtualname %url %code %referer %ua %query"
   ```